# Unable to Locate Elements through Automator Viewer on Login Pop-up Box

Tags: automated-testing, mobile

I am working on a mobile project, but I got stuck with it, as I cannot Locate any element for this Login pop-up Box through UIAutomator Viewer, the only elements being displayed by the UIAutomator viewer are the web Elements that are beneath the Login pop-up box.

How can I go about identifying the Username, Password input boxes, Sign In button and any other element(s) on this Login pop-up box.

[image]

Comment: I think you can , can you please expand that selected view? which is at right in you screenshot?

Comment: I have but no solution

Comment: Means? Please clarify.

Comment: I meant, The Elements on the Login -pop-up box can't be still identify through UIAutomator viewer.

Comment: what you are getting if you expand that selected view?

Comment: Am only getting all the Elements beneath the Login pop-up box not elements on the Login pop-up box

Comment: I have the same problem.
Estou com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

@solTesting, I guess, You are messed up pop-up view and background view in UIAutomator Viewer.

If not, Open using Appium inspector. Might you can expect better results !